# Version upgrade in Note does cause anything major?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Actually we are using notes 6.5. We are planning to upgrade it to 8.x. But we are maintaining a lot of databases approximately 50. If we upgrade the server. Does it cause anything major?

Comment: This is not a programming-related question. It is also broad, speculative, and quite frankly better answered by checking with your software vendor.

Comment: I do not want to teach a lession that this is how related to programming. Okay, Your rate is also not affect me. Try to answer that any of the Formuls or Lotus script class or any property make trouble.

Comment: I'd disagree with @CodeGnome. They are asking what to expect in changes in their applications when migrating to a later release.

Comment: @CodeGnome, it's similar to asking if there are any known problems moving from Java 1.6 to 1.7 -- one's own code is affected by the changes in the software. That is, Ramkumar himself is more like the software vendor than IBM.

Comment: -1 This question is too broad. It's like asking "Can R8.X break my custom application ?", and you are unable to articulate what you have in your environment. A more suitable question would be to ask about the upgrade process from 6.5=>8.x. The only meaningful answer is to advise setting up an 8.x test environment for regression testing.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question.  It's just hard to answer because it's not quite comparable to Java 1.6 to 1.7 as suggested by @David Navarre.  The time span between 6.5 and 8.5.3 makes it more like Java 1.3 to 1.7! Anyhow, there's more than the one reasonable answer suggested by Guulio -- though I do agree that testing is necessary no matter what.

Comment: Thanks all., Now I have a clear idea. But needs to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simon is correct that it *should* be backward compatible. Notes and Domino have an outstanding record of compatibility.  You should not have any major problems.  There's an occasional minor slip on IBM's part, but it is almost always treated as a bug and fixed in the next point release.  One exception is the @IfError function, which IBM has declared to be obsolete.

However you are talking about a big jump in versions, spanning a difference of over 8 years of product releases. I think that's too long a period to rely on people's memories about what minor problems have come up in all those years, but there is a company called TeamStudio that does a very good job of tracking such issues and has a product (TS Upgrade Filters) that will scan your applications to identify them.  In any case, I strongly advise you to create a test server and test your applications thoroughly.

Comment: Have you used the TS Filter Packs (fka Upgrade Filters) to know if they would scan the code of an Xpage and tell you what problems there might be after upgrading the server from 9.0.1 FP7 to 10.0.1 FP4?

Comment: No, I have not.

Answer (score 4):

It should be backward compatible. Upgrade the database ODS though to avoid any oddness. The new features are Composite Applications, Eclipse Plugins, Widgets/Live text and XPages. But you don't need to code these to get your earlier applications running.

I would also recommend reading "What's new in ..." sections of the Infocenter. It will detail any programatic features added/changed.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp

You have your question tagged as XPages, but there is no XPages in R6, so I am not sure that is relevant to what you are asking? (or can you expand?).

Comment: Sorry for that., I mentioned xpages because xpages developers might be worked R6 previously. Thanks... I accepted your's feedback.